# Test case for Struts2 2.3.24 using Strut2SpringTestCase (request object is coming as null)

Tags: unit-testing, struts2, junit4, el

I am trying to write unit test cases for my Struts2 action classes. My Test class extends `SpringStrutsTestCase` class. I am able to set the request object and able to get the action and action is also getting called but when in action it tries to get the parameters set in request object it throws null pointer exception i.e. request object is going as null. Below is my what my test class looks like. Any help is really appreciated.

```
    import org.apache.struts2.StrutsSpringTestCase;
    import org.junit.Test;

    import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionProxy;

    public class testClass extends StrutsSpringTestCase {

    @Test
    public void test1() throws Exception {
        try {
            request.setParameter("p1", "v1");
            request.setParameter("p2", "v2");
            ActionProxy proxy = getActionProxy("/actionName");
            MyActionClass loginAction = (MyActionClass) proxy.getAction();
            loginAction.execute();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getContextLocations() {
        String[] arr = new String[] { "one.xml", "two.xml", "three.xml" };
        return arr;
    }
}
```

Here is my action class.

```
public class MyAction extends ActionSupport{
private String p1;
private String p2;

/*
Gettere and Setters of p1 and p2
*/
    public String execute() throws Exception {
        // return "success";
        logger.info("Login Action Called");
        String pv1= (String) request.getParameter("p1");// If I get value using this.pv1 it works fine but with this code it doesn't.
        String pv2= (String) request.getParameter("p2");
        return "success";
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code for action won't compile. There is no declaration for `request`. Why do you use `request` at all? Get values from getters.

Comment: Yeah even I would have used that only but this code was written by someone and there so many places they have used this now I am facing too many issues while maintaining and fixing bug in it. Now to change all these such parameter might result in many other issues. And more ever there were no junit test written so that is major issue which I am facing. Any advice would be really helpful..:)

Comment: Where is the `request` coming from?

Comment: Look for `request =` in the code.

Comment: Here it is  HttpServletRequest request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();

Comment: Should be fine. Try to use `StrutsSpringJUnit4TestCase` instead of `StrutsSpringTestCase`.

Comment: Tried it now it is not able to get my application context it seems as my xml files having different names.In case of StrutsSpringTestCase I was overriding getContextLocations() to get those, but I am not sure how I can get those in case of StrutsSpringJunit4TestCase.

Comment: Override `getConfigPath` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to test an action call you need to call `execute` method of  `ActionProxy`. By calling `execute` of your action you are just invoking that particular method of the action class and not S2 action along with the interceptors, results, etc.

The correct way would be:

```
ActionProxy proxy = getActionProxy("/actionName");
proxy.execute();
```

BTW if you're using JUnit 4 there is `StrutsSpringJUnit4TestCase` which you should use instead of `StrutsSpringTestCase`.

Comment: Thank you ALeksandr Action seems to be getting called now but request object is still going as null only. I am getting the values of the variables as well which are declared in action class but not getting the values when trying to get using request.getParameter() as request is null.

Comment: @GauravParek Show your action. How do you get request?

Comment: Normal way only, it is creating a url and which is then calling action(ajax call). And in that call it is able to get the request object but the issue is when I am trying to mock it using junit. Let me know if I didn't answer clearly to your question.